# Date object creation fails in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm getting very strange error in JavaScript.

```
var stamp = 1349102;
var obj = {a: stamp, b: new Date(stamp), c: new Date(1349102)};
```

When I look into `obj` - `b` says *invalid Date* but `c` is valid `Date` object.

Please help me. I really don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: did you mean the final ) to be there?

Comment: Works for me, without the extra left paren: obj.b.toString() === obj.c.toString()

Comment: well, the stamp var isnt constant, its value comes from input

Comment: Works for me too : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/27/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `stamp` is provided by a user, it can be considered as string. In that case your code would be interpreted by a browser as the following code (which does not work):

```
var stamp = "1349102";
var obj = {a: stamp, b: new Date(stamp), c: new Date(1349102)};
```

Convert `stamp` to [Number](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp) and it will be fine

```
var stamp = "1349102";
var obj = {a: stamp, b: new Date(Number(stamp)), c: new Date(1349102)};
```

See the console output: first is without `Number` conversion, second is with `Number` conversion.

[image: JSON Console Output]

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem ;)